# Deserialize multi-part JSON with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, serialization

I'm fairly new to the awesomeness that is JSON - I'm using the DataContractJsonSerializer. I cannot get the multiple instances of the Customer objects into the list.

The Attributes work as expected but there are no Customer objects in my List..??

```
{
    "@attributes":
        {"count":"2",
        "offset":"0",
        "limit":"100"
        },
    "Customer":
        {
            "firstName":"cust ",
            "lastName":"one",
            "title":"Owner",
            "company":"CustOne Plants",
            "companyRegistrationNumber":"",
            "vatNumber":"",
            "creditAccountID":"1",
            "customerTypeID":"4",
            "discountID":"0",
            "taxCategoryID":"0",
            "customerID":"1",
            "createTime":"2017-06-19T23:36:11+00:00",
            "timeStamp":"2017-06-20T18:55:11+00:00",
            "archived":"false"
         }
    "Customer":
        {
            "firstName":"cust ",
            "lastName":"two",
            "title":"Owner",
            "company":"CustTwo House of Games",
            "companyRegistrationNumber":"",
            "vatNumber":"",
            "creditAccountID":"1",
            "customerTypeID":"4",
            "discountID":"0",
            "taxCategoryID":"0",
            "customerID":"1",
            "createTime":"2017-06-19T23:36:11+00:00",
            "timeStamp":"2017-06-20T18:55:11+00:00",
            "archived":"false"
         }
}
```

.NET code:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\TMC Projects\PotteryManufacturing\CustomerJSON.txt");
string text = stream.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomersRoot));
var varInfo = serializer.ReadObject(stream1) as CustomersRoot;
stream1.Close();
```

and finally my classes/data contracts/data members:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomersRoot
{
    private List<Customer> m_Customers;

    public CustomersRoot() { this.Customer = new List<Customer>(); }
    [DataMember(Name ="@attributes")]
    public Attributes attrs { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Customer")]
    public List<Customer> Customer
    {
        get { return m_Customers; }
        set { m_Customers = value; }
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name ="firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "lastName")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "company")]
    public string company { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "companyRegistrationNumber")]
    public string companyRegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "vatNumber")]
    public string vatNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "creditAccountID")]
    public int creditAccountID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "customerTypeID")]
    public int customerTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "discountID")]
    public int discountID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "taxCategoryID")]
    public int taxCategoryID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "customerID")]
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "createTime")]
    public string createTime { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "timeStamp")]
    public string timeStamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "archived")]
    public bool archived { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Attributes
{
    [DataMember(Name = "count")]
    public int count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "offset")]
    public int offset { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "limit")]
    public int limit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm updating with new code so you all can see where I'm at - still not working but I know there has to be a way.

Comment: If you read the documentation for [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), it specifically states "Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization."

Comment: LOL - really? That's terrible! Oh well, luckily these same  web  services have an XML endpoint  and deserializing XML is EASY AS PIE! :)

Comment: Deserialization with JSON.Net is extremely simple, has lots of options, and there are many examples here and on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what's going on here - the call can sometimes return an array of Customer objects (not formatted correctly above) OR a single instance of the object. When the web service returns a single Customer instance, the List code does not work. I will have to check on how to deal w/ this issue.